# Where can I get the 'X-DocuSign-AppToken' for the demo Account? Where I get the Distributor Code & Password for my Demo Account or Trial Account?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to invoke the **Accounts: getProvisioning GET /v2.1/accounts/provisioning** API with my Demo Account. But I'm getting this response

{

"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",

"message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. An application token must be specified in the 'X-DocuSign-AppToken' header."

}

Where I get the Distributor Code & Password for my Demo Account or Trial Account?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an official DocuSign ISV/Partner/Reseller in order to use the provisioning API and create new accounts.
You can engage the team by [email](http://mailto:partner@docusign.com) at [partner portal.](https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner)